# Get TimeZone name or abbreviation from long timezone string

Tags: javascript, momentjs, powerbi

I am using a third party API which gives me few events and their timings, with the timezone user selected. but the timezone is in long string format and i am not able to parse it as proper timezone.

response i am getting

```
{
    "days": [
        "Sunday",
        "Monday",
        "Tuesday",
        "Wednesday",
        "Thursday",
        "Friday",
        "Saturday"
    ],
    "times": [
        "07:00",
        "08:00",
        "09:00",
        "10:00",
        "11:00",
        "12:00",
        "14:00",
        "15:00"
    ],
    "localTimeZoneId": "Central Standard Time",
}
```

i just want to convert this windows format timezone to IANA timezone format.

Comment: Can you be specific about iana time zone? https://gist.github.com/danderson00/c03d46dfc38486ea7b06da9f75c7a63f

Comment: Thanks, this will work for me, but is there any direct method in JS or PHP?